# Retornar empresa do usuário usando a matricula

Tags: advpl

estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web integrada com o Protheus.

A questão é que existem diversas empresas cadastradas no Protheus, e eu preciso saber a qual empresa/filial o usuário pertence, sendo que tudo o que peço para ele informar na autenticação da aplicação web é usuário e senha.

Minha dúvida é se é possível retornar a empresa a qual o usuário pertence apenas pela matricula, ou se é melhor perguntar no momento da autenticação a qual empresa o usuário pretende logar.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue trabalhar no código base?
Se sim, você pode tentar usar join.

Tipo:

```sql
select nome from tbl_empresa e join tbl_usuario u on u.empresa_id = e.id;
```

Substituindo, é claro, os nomes das tabelas.

Otherwise, se não tiver acesso, me fala e eu dou mais uma olhada.

Comment: Oi Bianca, quanto a query é tranquilo, a questão é que não sei se é possível no Protheus retornar a empresa do usuário através da matricula.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema adicionando um select na página de autenticação lendo a tabela SM0, onde consigo retornar as empresas cadastradas, agora eu sei a que empresa o usuário pertence ao se autenticar, obrigado pela ajuda!